# HostRegexp failed

Tags: regex, go, traefik

i'm trying to use Traefik HostRegexp for a frontend rule.
i was trying something like this:

```
HostRegexp:{subdomain:.+}.p([0-9]+)+(env1|env2).mydomain.com
```

But this doesn't work as i wanted.

I wanted traefik to route to my apache server when these kind of URL as used:

`A.B.C.pXX.env1.mydomain.com
A.B.C.pXX.env2.mydomain.com`

any clues ? what have i done wrong with my regexp ?

Comment: I believe the regexp must be enclosed in the curly braces, your regexp is in and out side of the curly braces.. i think you should do something like this `{subdomain: ..your regexp here.. }.mydomain.com`

Comment: and also replace `+` before `(env|` with `\.`, ie `.p([0-9]+)\.(env1|env2)` . Better to use escaped dots instead of a single dot

Comment: @AvinashRaj \. drops an error in traefik :
` invalid escape character '.'; only the following escape characters are allowed: \b, \t, \n, \f, \r, \", \\, \uXXXX, and \UXXXXXXXX`

Answer (score 0):

The correct `regexp` is:

```
HostRegexp:{subdomain:.+.p([0-9]+)+(crm|ecom)}.mydomain.com
```